# Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, twitter

I am using `TWTweetComposeViewController` for iOS 5 legacy in my app. For some reason, I am receiving a `"Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2" error."` I have tried looking for answers in similar questions, but they haven't helped me so far.

Here is the code:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet =
                [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
                [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"%@", [[_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"redirect_url"]];
                [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the error says, you have too many arguments. You need to use NSString's stringWithFormat method to create your dynamic string:

```
[tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"redirect_url"]]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object];` to make a format string.

Comment: You mean like this?:

`[tweetSheet setInitialText:@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"redirect_url"]]];`

Because it's still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because Xcode auto completed *stringWith...* to `stringWithString:` instead of the intended `stringWithFormat:`. Took some time to find what was wrong, so check that you're actually using the correct method.